# XML, avoid duplicated tags

Tags: xml, duplicates

I am dealing with an XML but I've barely used them in the past.
Given an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testi>
    <page_title>Page Title</page_title>
    <hello_world>Hello World!</hello_world>
    <address>Address</address>
    ...long lines here...
</testi>
```

Ho can I be sure that entries within `<testi>` tag are not duplicated? I'd like to avoid something like this, because it will mess my document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<testi>
    <page_title>Page Title</page_title>
    <hello_world>Hello World!</hello_world>
    <address>Address</address>
    ...long lines here...
    ...very long lines...
    <address>Address again, this should not be permitted because there is yet address tag!</address>
</testi>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can validate the XML against a DTD or XML Schema.

Answer (score 1):

### Detection

Commonly you'd specify declaratively what elements could appear within `testi` using a standard schema language such as XSD.  You could then use a validating parser to report whether any given XML document conforms to the constraints in the XSD.

Alternatively, you could use an XML parser in a language of your choice and have your code keep track of the constraints that matter to you, such as the number of occurrences of `address` in `testi`.

### Correction

If you wish to eliminate the duplicate elements, the standard approach is to write XSLT, which is designed to parse and transform XML.

Alternatively, you could use the lower level APIs of XML parsers in a language of your choice and have your code filter the unwanted `address` elements.